# Cannot send data from Excel to Googlespreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I really need help on this.
Currently I'm developing a Personalisation Progress Report System where teacher can key in all the data for student progress.
I'm create the system using Excel by Developer mode (Visual Basic)

As I write the pre-filled link in the visual basic, the line is too long. Hence, I cannot send the data to the google spreadsheet.

I provide the code for references.

```
Sub SendToGoogle()
Dim URL_First As String
Dim URL_Last1 As String
Dim URL_Last2 As String
Dim URL_Last3 As String
Dim URL_Last4 As String

Dim Form_URL1 As String
Dim Form_URL2 As String
Dim Form_URL3 As String
Dim Form_URL4 As String
 
Dim HeaderName As String
Dim SendID As String

Dim TicketInfo As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

HeaderName = "Content-Type"

SendID = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
 
URL_First = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScjgaoQH2OY8_g7ZbgAZV7EA7bm6Hd0_dZskW7eQgqzObZQBA/formResponse?ifq"
URL_Last1 = "usp=pp_url&entry.1417086696=" & TeachersName & "&entry.1480907186=" & StudentName & "&entry.23393781=" & Age & "&entry.1787044956=" & DesignatedClass & "&entry.1336617490=" & MonthlyGoalsStatus & "&entry.855024799=" & MonthlyGoal & "&entry.1901482332=" & BMLevel & "&entry.283000664=" & EnglishLevel & "&entry.1518036587=" & MathLevel & "&entry.572588401=" & ScienceLevel & "&entry.362894336=" & IslamicLevel & "&entry.7094834=" & IndependentLevel & "&entry.1235784544=" & ArtLevel & "&entry.1146817666=" & JawiLevel & "&entry.941320954=" & IqraLevel & "&entry.2057356014=" & CambridgeLevel & "&entry.167021318=" & TechLevel & "&entry.537964950=" & LeaderLevel & "&entry.1173893187=" & PublicLevel & "&entry.771775066=" & RoboticLevel & "&entry.479434689=" & MathPLUSLevel & "&entry.892406885=" & BakingLevel & "&entry.1106219517=" & BrickLevel & "&entry.116139854=" & PhysicalLevel & "&entry.789971300=" & BMStatus & "&entry.198791007=" & EnglishStatus & "&entry.1991286245=" & MathStatus & "&submit=Submit"
URL_Last2 = "&entry.231856359=" & ScienceStatus & "&entry.1895003914=" & IslamicStatus & "&entry.997911219=" & IndependentStatus & "&entry.1195842579=" & ArtStatus & "&entry.135297141=" & JawiStatus & "&entry.65828675=" & IqraStatus & "&entry.489324965=" & CambridgeStatus & "&entry.725694321=" & TechStatus & "&entry.63116833=" & LeaderStatus & "&entry.1929148142=" & PublicStatus & "&entry.428565794=" & RoboticStatus & "&entry.1931195002=" & MathPLUSStatus & "&entry.389281264=" & BakingStatus & "&entry.264953265=" & BrickStatus & "&entry.402102536=" & PhysicalStatus & "&entry.902060269=" & BMComment & "&entry.130882209=" & EnglishComment & "&entry.2104221501=" & MathComment & "&entry.1584171548=" & ScienceComment & "&entry.308169846" & IslamicComment & "&entry.1778216349=" & IndependentComment & "&entry.1888240101=" & ArtComment & "&entry.746401376=" & JawiComment & "&entry.1750886136=" & IqraComment & "&entry.736281504=" & CambridgeComment & "&entry.716508565=" & TechComment & "&submit=Submit"
URL_Last3 = "&entry.1192188084=" & LeaderComment & "&entry.1828566042=" & PublicComment & "&entry.653415414=" & RoboticComment & "&entry.943404131=" & MathPLUSComment & "&entry.500469194=" & BakingComment & "&entry.524429676=" & BrickComment & "&entry.2006146722=" & PhysicalComment & "&entry.1195839299=" & BMOtherComment & "&entry.572497393=" & EnglishOtherComment & "&entry.1779781765=" & MathOtherComment & "&entry.1443549238=" & ScienceOtherComment & "&entry.91600726=" & IslamicOtherComment & "&entry.600022209=" & IndependentOtherComment & "&entry.499331422=" & ArtOtherComment & "&entry.699366184=" & JawiOtherComment & "&entry.687267933=" & IqraOtherComment & "&entry.494442256=" & CambridgeOtherComment & "&entry.270986380=" & TechOtherComment & "&entry.70939666=" & LeaderOtherComment & "&entry.1906540560=" & PublicOtherComment & "&entry.1287355695=" & RoboticOtherComment & "&entry.393486256=" & MathPLUSOtherComment & "&entry.1679577233=" & BakingOtherComment & "&submit=Submit"
URL_Last4 = "&entry.1304233785=" & BrickOtherComment & "&entry.730291442=" & PhysicalOtherComment & "&submit=Submit"
 

'Creating the Final URL
Form_URL1 = URL_First & URL_Last1
Form_URL2 = Form_URL1 & URL_Last2
Form_URL3 = Form_URL2 & URL_Last3
Form_URL4 = Form_URL3 & URL_Last4
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but the combination of all of that information is _one_ URL?

Comment: yes, it is from one url link. but the line is too long for one line in vba. May i know, how can i write the whole one url continuosly?

Comment: Your code worked for me for writing the URL to a cell in Excel.

Comment: I've been having trouble with character limits recently. Just wondering, for your issue, were you able to find a solution? And have you tried programmatically reading the desired Google spreadsheet cell/location for it's current URL text? If there is URL text, could you then `len(text)+1` and loop, placing each URL piece after the current URL text?